# iOS Safari cache on Back Button

Tags: html, css, ios, caching, safari

I was curious if anyone has encountered the following issue in iOS Safari:

- User navigates to site
- User clicks on Nav Item
- Nav Item clicked displays Sub Nav
- User clicks a sub nav item
- User then clicks the back button
- The sub nav is open automatically (problem)

When you initially click on a main nav item, it should display the sub nav. This happens initially, but when the user goes to a sub nav item page and then clicks the back button, that sub nav is open automatically. When the user clicks the forward button, it goes to the sub nav items page and that nav is still open.

Unless you do a hard refresh the page seems to cache the previous pages state, including the  users interaction.

Heres a basic example of what the markup and styling are:

http://jsfiddle.net/alvincrespo/s5UYY/

Any clues/help would be very much appreciated.

[UPDATE]

The above link is just an example to show the markup and CSS. The actual links on the site are not hashtags, they do have actual links going to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page isn't actually leaving the current page, its href is an anchor location on the page and will not do a hard page refresh. Are you using the History API?

Also just an FYI, I can't reproduce this in JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks! The above links are just samples for the HTML and CSS, the actual site doesn't have hash tags and doesn't tie into the History API.

Comment: Adding my response here too.

iOS doesn't support :hover, so you'll get weird shit like that happening. My suggestion is to use Modernizr or some other workaround to reset those nav states on page refresh.